# How to get the memory used of a .exe using command prompt

Tags: memory, command-line, command-prompt

Using the command prompt, how can i get the memory used when executing a .exe. For example, to find the time taken i can use a .bat file as follows:

```
@echo off
time < nul
Function.exe
time < nul
```

How can i do this for memory used?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
mem | find "available to MS-DOS"
function.exe
mem | find "available to MS-DOS"
```

Output from the `mem` command (example):

```
655360 bytes total conventional memory
655360 bytes available to MS-DOS
599312 largest executable program size

1048576 bytes total contiguous extended memory
     0 bytes available contiguous extended memory
941056 bytes available XMS memory
       MS-DOS resident in High Memory Area
```

Btw. instead of `time <nul` you can use `time /t`.

Comment: mem isn't available in Vista/Windows 7 i don't think.

Comment: or at least 64-bit versions of Windows 7 anyway.

Comment: Windows 7: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343190/how-to-check-available-memory-ram-via-batch-script)