# How to get the memory sized of .exe file using command prompt on Windows

Tags: windows, memory, command-line, command-prompt

I'd like to get memory size exe file when I run it on command prompt.

In case of Linux I can get memory size as followings.

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v ./test.exee here
```

How do I get memory size on Windows?
I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785457/how-to-get-the-memory-used-of-a-exe-using-command-prompt), but it doesn't work for me.

Condition: windows10 on remote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you go to directory and order by size and find your file ?

cd /directory 
Dir /S search all folders in sub directory 
And use * ______ sortorder S

Okay, you can use a wmic queue to get the space of process after getting the process ID

Something like this should work

C:\wmic process where processid="processID" get workingsetsize

Comment: I'd like to check used memory size(like RSS) while running. It"s not file size.
Thank you.

Comment: did this help you by any chance ?, if it didn't please clarify more.